# How can I solve this problem Broken DAG [/PATH/] module 'typing' jas no attribute NoReturn?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, typing

I'm trying to create a Dataproc DAG with Airflow 1.7 and Python 3.6 this is my code

```
`from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator import DataprocClusterCreateOperator, DataProcPySparkOperator, DataprocClusterDeleteOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 3, 1),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    'example_dataproc_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
)

create_cluster = DataprocClusterCreateOperator(
    task_id='create_dataproc_cluster',
    cluster_name='example-cluster',
    project_id='your-project-id',
    num_workers=2,
    zone='us-central1-b',
    master_machine_type='n1-standard-2',
    worker_machine_type='n1-standard-2',
    dag=dag
)

run_spark_job = DataProcPySparkOperator(
    task_id='run_spark_job',
    main='gs://your-bucket/your-script.py',
    cluster_name='example-cluster',
    project_id='your-project-id',
    region='us-central1',
    dag=dag
)

delete_cluster = DataprocClusterDeleteOperator(
    task_id='delete_dataproc_cluster',
    cluster_name='example-cluster',
    project_id='your-project-id',
    region='us-central1',
    dag=dag
)
create_cluster >> run_spark_job >> delete_cluster`
```

i don't understand why Airflow show me that error

I hope if everything can help me with this issue, I was tried importing the typing library but it doesn't work. If someone had the same issue, it will be excellent if you can share me. Thanks for reading community

Comment: You're trying to use some library that isn't compatible with Python 3.6.

Comment: Which version of python is compatible ?

Comment: I dunno, but to not have `typing.NoReturn`, you would have to be on a Python version lower than 3.6.2 (because `typing.NoReturn` was introduced in the 3.5.4 and 3.6.2 bugfix releases for some reason). Your Python is seriously out of date.